# ¿Cuál es el origen del dicho "nadar entre dos aguas"? ¿Se utiliza sólo en España o es común también en otros países?

Tags: modismos

"Nadar entre dos aguas" suele referirse al intento de evitar comprometerse con un rumbo determinado cuando se presentan dos alternativas e implica que no elegir es el camino más peligroso, pero he encontrado este ejemplo también: ["El presidente de EEUU sabe 'nadar entre dos aguas', opina el politólogo"](https://mundo.sputniknews.com/20160303/obama-sanciones-rusia-ue-experto-1057320419.html) lo que parece significar mantener un equilibrio delicado.

[Este articulo](https://www.milenio.com/opinion/gil-games/uno-hasta-el-fondo/dichos-y-frases-hechas) sugiere que tiene un origen marítimo, en referencia a la peligrosa confluencia de corrientes provocada por un río que desemboca en el mar.  No da detalles y parece que explicaría mejor la variante "estar entre dos aguas."

[Esta obra](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL27317415M/Nadar_entre_dos_aguas) sugiere que era de uso común hacia el año 1871, si no antes.

Comment: Gracias, Sisifo.  He añadado el significado.

Answer (score 2):

Como todo dicho, puede que en la propia España haya variaciones, según las provincias. Sin embargo, creo que en general es fácil de comprender su significado para los hispano hablantes, teniendo el contexto.
No se puede "rendir cuentas a dos patrones" / "jugar para ambos equipos" son casos similares (ignoro si son usados en España).

No se debe "nadar entre dos aguas", es peligroso (o poco ético según el contexto). No significa como tal que no se pueda hacer, de ahí que el titular diga que el presidente sabe hacerlo, equilibradamente sin perder el juego contra una de las dos partes.

Answer (score 1):

---

Que tal!

La cuestión que planteas es doble;

- Por una parte ¿Cuál es el origen del dicho "nadar entre dos aguas"?
- Y por otro, el sentido de la frase: "*El presidente de EEUU sabe nadar entre dos aguas*". En este último caso, como muy bien has expresado, obviamente se entiende el sentido de *poseer la habilidad* de ser capaz por sostenerse entre dos posturas distantes sin decantarse por ninguna.

Por otro lado, y siguiendo con los enunciados que siguen, el artículo que citas  "en referencia a la peligrosa confluencia de corrientes provocada por un río que desemboca en el mar", sugiriendo este tipo de origen, no tiene mayor transcendencia, el ámbito de la expresión no se encuentra en las corrientes.
Por último, la entretenida obra teatral en verso, "El Nadar entre dos aguas" de Eduardo Navarro, al final cuando dice;

"*No más luchas con enaguas, me caso, y no tuerzo el gesto. Señores que es muy expuesto el nadar entre dos aguas*". Claramente indica lo difícil que es mantener dos posturas a la vez, en este caso, casarse y no casarse, sin decantarse de manera clara por ninguna.

Esto me hizo sospechar que seguramente su origen poco ó nada tenía ya que ver con lo que se entiende actualmente por, "Nadar entre dos aguas" ó al menos las acepciones se había desvirtuado y evolucionado mezclando otras referencias a lo largo del tiempo.

---

En este sentido y curiosamente, existen varias versiones sobre este dicho "*nadar entre dos aguas*", "navegar entre dos aguas", "*estar entre dos aguas*", que a su vez reflejan varias de las ideas expuestas y a veces otras distintas que se encuentran muy alejadas entre si. Ejem.;

- Ser indeciso, no poder decidirse por uno u otro lado. Ejem. Estoy entre dos aguas, no se si estudiar ó trabajar.
- Mantener una actitud equivocada tratando de satisfacer al mismo tiempo a dos partes opuestas.
- Indica entre dos opciones o cosas opuestas.
- Estar en un dilema contradictorio.
- Estar en dos mentes.
- Entre dos momentos.
- Con duda y perplejidad, o equívocamente, por reserva o cautela.
- Obtener una negativa o rechazo ante una petición. No seguir el consejo dado por alguien.

---

El origen de la expresión *Española* "***nadar entre dos aguas***", aparecerá dentro de los primeros comienzos de la natación, aunque también referido a otras cosas.

Respecto a la historia de la natación, fue oficialmente Nicolaus Wynman, quien escribió el primer libro sobre esta actividad en 1538 "Colymbetes, sive de arte Natandi et Festivius et lucundus Lectu", también existe otro anterior de 1531. En 1587 De Arte Natandi", traducido del Latín al Inglés, al Francés y de aquí al Italiano, Alemán y Español. En los que se explica en antiguo tono, Maestro y discípulo, las técnicas y los distintos tipos de disfrutar de este tipo de baño.

Siguiendo el estudio de todos estos libros y otros diccionarios hasta la actualidad, podemos concluir que la procedencia es del ámbito de la natación y marino, así se entiende por "*nadar entre dos aguas*", el hecho de sumergirse sin llegar al fondo quedando suspendido, en una especie de equilibrio entre las aguas superiores e inferiores.
Por otro lado el término también se identifica con el de tomar, buscar, coger ó ganar las aguas de un buque para ponerse en ellas.

En un libro de 1818 aparecían los dos estilos de natación principales, el estilo braza, también llamado pecho, considerado el primero, históricamente hablando, y el estilo dorsal o de espalda, que eran básicamente los existentes. A ello hacia referencia a nadar...entre dos aguas.

Por otro lado estilo crol, fue visto por primera vez en 1844 en una competición en Londres y el estilo llamado mariposa a mediados de los años 20' del Siglo XX, y por tanto son posteriores y quedan descartados.

- Así, mantenerse en el agua *sumergido* en equilibrio entre las aguas superiores e inferiores moviendo los pies y las manos en lo que que diríamos, **nadar buceando** coloquialmente, sin especificar más, recibía antiguamente el nombre de "nadar entre dos aguas".
- El sentido original ha intentado mutar hacia otras peripecias y acepciones, intentando forzar y confundir con el aspecto numérico de la expresión, *dos aguas*, como si esas dos "aguas" fueran a su vez, dos problemas, puntos extremos u opiniones distantes, cuando en realidad a lo que hace referencia es a una parte del agua más sumergida y a otra que se encuentra más en la superficie, en equilibrio entre las dos.
  El equilibrio se establece cuando existen dos *fuerzas* que empujan opuestas y que tienen lugar simultáneamente a la vez.
  Es esta parte ó sentido último de "equilibrio" es al que hay que prestar atención y no confundirse con el fragmento "*entre dos aguas*", que nos puede confundir.

Lo importante es entender que esas dos partes, dos aguas, aguas superiores y aguas inferiores son las que nos mantienen en equilibrio, de ahí que se hayan dado algunas de las acepciones más arriba expuestas. La acepción de *peligro*, proviene de lo que suponía antiguamente estar debajo del agua sin respirar, ello acrecentaba la incertidumbre de salir ó no salir a la superficie, de ahí el acento sobre la ambivalencia de la expresión.

Sin embargo, volvamos al comienzo, a la frase enunciada;

```
    **"El presidente de EEUU sabe nadar entre dos aguas".**
```

Con lo que sabemos, podríamos enunciar la frase;

```
    *"El presidente de EEUU sabe mantenerse en equilibrio".*
    *"El presidente de EEUU concilia en el conflicto".*
```

La noticia podría quedar;

**"Obama sabe mantenerse en equilibrio: hace una semana logró un acuerdo sobre Siria con Vladímir Putin. Pero al mismo tiempo, demuestra que EEUU todavía busca una confrontación con Rusia", comentó el politólogo.**

Creo que sobran las palabras y se entiende perfectamente.

Espero haber ayudado. Saludos. Diego M.